# Use library into several projects in appcelerator studio

Tags: javascript, optimization, shared-libraries, appcelerator

I'm using custom javascript libraries in appcelerator studio but some of them are needed in several projects.
Now I'm looking for a method to "synchronize" these files in all of my projects. To avoid having to repeat each modification in each projects

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to isolate your custom library (as a node module) in a separate (private) git repository and define a dependency on that library in your appc project.

To create your library:

Install *https://github.com/FokkeZB/appc-npm* and create your library via *appc-npm*, eg. ***appc-npm lib***. (this will generate a node module of your library and will enrich this module with an install hook which will copy your library file to your appc project's lib folder. Just make sure not to publish it(to a public node repo).

However, be careful, you will probably not want to publish your library in the global node repository. That's no problem, you can also install node artifacts directly from (private) github.

To consume your library:

Next you must initialize your application as an nodejs project:

```
npm init
```

This will generate a package.json

Now you can manually install your library from your private github repo.

```
npm install git+ssh://privategit.acme.inc:9876/projectname/<MODULE>.git#<TAG_OR_BRANCH> --save-dev
```

or you can list your dependency in your package.json

Comment: this approach is good because it will keep your code safe online. Another approach I believe is to put your commonJS file in modules folder and add it through tiapp.xml file.

But I am not sure how to package a common js native module.

Anyways, I don't see any point in doing so because common JS modules can simply be added in application lib folder. it's just a few seconds task.

Comment: We (more or less) follow the approach outlined above. Moreover we version our libraries. This makes reuse of (a version of) a library between apps really as simple as just updating the version number of the dependency.